# struts 2 datepicker not loading after jquery post function

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am working with struts 2 jquery 
after post action  "addEmployeeFromTree" the input_employee.jsp form
is loaded but only label of dateandtimepicker displayed and not showing the calender

```
<ul id="myPost" class="contextMenu">
    <li class="copy separator"><a href="#add">Add Employee</a></li>
</ul>

function(action, el, pos) {
    if(action == 'add'){                            
        $.post("addEmployeeFromTree","positionId="+ $(el).attr('id').substring(5),function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        });
    }
}
```

mapping file

```
<action name="addEmployeeFromTree" class="hris.employee.action.EmployeeAction" method="getPost1">
    <result>/jsp/employee/input_employee.jsp</result>
</action>
```

input_employee.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <sx:datetimepicker name="passportExpirationDate" value="% {employee.passportExpirationDate}"  displayFormat="%{#application.dateFormat}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: if you wanna people help you, you should at least show some respect and make your code readable, not just copy and paste.

Comment: Are there any js errors?